# Cat6a RJ45 connector does not connect

Tags: networking, connector, rj-45

I have Cat6a S/FTP Shielded cable, TP-Link TL-SG1024 (24 port) switch, deleyCON Cat6a wall sockets (with 2 RJ45 ports) and a Cat6a deleyCON (24 port) switch panel. I bought Cat6a RJ45 connector (FTP Shielded 8p 8c 3u-50u) but the connector doesn't seem to plug into any of my equipment (patch panel, switch or wall sockets). Can someone advice on why that is the case? and how I can resolve the issue? or do I have to buy a different type of connector?
I can provide pics or anyother information if required. Just to explain, when I try to connect the connector to any of the equipment, there seems to be a ridge at the top of the connector that is stopping it going into the slots
Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: What is a connector (vs a cable)? Does your cable not have a male connector on it?

Comment: By connector I mean the actual RJ45 connector. My cable doesn't have the RJ45 connector at the end (mainly because I bought the cable in bulk to lay down wired network at home). I have RJ45 connectors that I will connect to the end of the cable. Hope this helps

Comment: As far as I know there is only one standard for RJ 45 connectors. I don't know what would be wrong...

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but apparently that's not the case

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the business end of the connector as well as any details on the packaging?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I hadn't crimped the connector. I just did and it fits ok now

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault. I hadn't crimped the connector. Once I crimped it, it now fits fine. However, the connectors come with a funny load bar where both ends are the same so it looks like i'll have to stager it manually.. unless I can get load bars with hollow end. Sorry guys